# Trying to add a self signed SSL certificate to a .NET CORE webapi

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ssl, webapi, kestrel-http-server

I run a .NET CORE webapi in a local network and I'm trying to make the communication https. I generated a self signed SSL certificate and I'm now trying to add that to the webserver that runs via Kestrel.

I already got it working by loading the same certificate that I saved in the project folder into a X509Certificate2 object. The server starts and I can access over https perfectly fine.

But when I'm trying to use that same certificate that is installed in the certificate store, I get the error: `Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established` when trying to reach the web address.

I checked both X509Certificate2 objects before I load them and they look exactly the same, except for the Handle property.

This is my Kestrel setup:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder
                    .UseKestrel(
                    options =>
                    {
                        var certificate = new X509Certificate2("localhost.pfx", "YourSecurePassword");
                        string lovThumbprint = "d822eebae68129f0fd10295060963bbf41101231";
                        var lovCertificateFromStore = GetCertificateByThumbprint(lovThumbprint);
                        options.AddServerHeader = false;
                        options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 5001, listenOptions =>
                        {
                            //when using lovCertificateFromStore , I get the TLS error
                            listenOptions.UseHttps(certificate);
                        });
                    }
                )
                    .UseUrls("https://0.0.0.0:5001")
                    .UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
```

And this is the function to get the certificate from the certificate store:

````
private static X509Certificate2 GetCertificateByThumbprint(string povThumbprint)
        {
            using (var store = new X509Store(StoreName.CertificateAuthority, StoreLocation.LocalMachine))
            {
                store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
                var certificates = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, povThumbprint, validOnly: false);
                return certificates.Count > 0 ? certificates[0] : null;
            }
        }```
````

Comment: Do you add Child Certificate in Chrome Browser  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I generated my X509Certificate2 was wrong. I had to enable the PersistKeySet flag of the generated certificate to make it work.

```
var cert = new X509Certificate2(lovFilePath, "" , X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
```