# ASP.NET Core Web API with SSL - local file of self-signed certificate

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ssl, asp.net-web-api, x509certificate2

I need the created ASP.NET Core Web API to use HTTPS with a self-signed certificate. This self-signed certificate may or may not have a password and associated private key. The input files `certificate.crt` and `certificate.key`, as well as the certificate password, are configured by the user in an application settings form and saved in a file `AppSettings.xml`.

During the application's execution, no errors or exceptions are generated. However, when accessing an endpoint of the application, the following error is returned:

> Error: Client network socket disconnected before a secure TLS connection was established

Note: The application works perfectly when I use `CertificateLoader.LoadFromStoreCert()`, but it is essential that it works when importing the `.crt` and `.key` files configured by my client.

EDIT [11/08/2023] - by author

I made some changes to the code following suggestions from **Wiktor Zychla**. Now, the `SslProtocols` of the `Kestrel` server is configured with either `SslProtocols.Tls12` or `SslProtocols.Tls13`, respecting the `SSL` configuration that the operating system supports. Additionally, it includes a new certificate loading method, the `LoadCertificate`, which retrieves the certificate's path and private key from the software's configuration file. The `SaveCertificate` method installs the certificate that the user imported, along with its private key and password (if applicable).

```cs
var httpHostBuilder = new WebHostBuilder()
    .UseKestrel(options =>
    {
      options.ListenAnyIP(appProperties.ServerPort, listenOptions =>
      {
        var certificate = HttpServerHandler.LoadCertificate(appProperties);

        listenOptions.UseHttps(httpsOptions =>
        {
          httpsOptions.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12 | SslProtocols.Tls13;
          httpsOptions.ServerCertificateSelector = (connectionContext, name) =>
          {
            if (certificate != null)
              return certificate;

            return null;
          };
        });
      });
    });
```

```cs
public void SaveCertificate()
{
  if (AppProperties.CertFilePath != null && File.Exists(AppProperties.CertFilePath))
    certFilePath = AppProperties.CertFilePath;

  passwordCert = string.IsNullOrEmpty(AppProperties.PasswordCertificate) ? string.Empty : textBoxPasswordCertificate.Texts;

  if (AppProperties.KeyFilePath != null && File.Exists(AppProperties.KeyFilePath))
    keyFilePath = AppProperties.KeyFilePath;


  var certificate = new X509Certificate2(certFilePath, passwordCert, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyFilePath))
  {
    byte[] privateKeyBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(keyFilePath);

    using (var privateKeyStream = new MemoryStream(privateKeyBytes))
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(privateKeyStream))
    {
      string privateKeyContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
      RSA privateKey = RSA.Create();
      privateKey.ImportFromPem(privateKeyContent);

      certificate = certificate.CopyWithPrivateKey(privateKey);
    }
  }

  InstallCertificate(certificate);

  ConfirmCertificate(certificate);

  TrustCertificate(certificate.Thumbprint);
}


public void InstallCertificate(X509Certificate2 certificate)
{
  using (X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.CurrentUser))
  {
    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
    store.Add(certificate);
    store.Close();
  }

  using (X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser))
  {
    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
    store.Add(certificate);
    store.Close();
  }
}

public void ConfirmCertificate(X509Certificate2 certificate)
{
  using (X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.CurrentUser))
  {
    store.Open(OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly | OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
    store.Certificates.Add(certificate);
    store.Close();
  }

  using (X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser))
  {
    store.Open(OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly | OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
    store.Certificates.Add(certificate);
    store.Close();
  }
}


public void TrustCertificate(string certificateThumbprint)
{
  using (X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.CurrentUser))
  {
    try
    {
      store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);

      X509Certificate2Collection certificates = store.Certificates.Find(
          X509FindType.FindByThumbprint,
          certificateThumbprint,
          validOnly: false);

      if (certificates.Count > 0)
      {
        X509Certificate2 certificate = certificates[0];
        
        X509Chain chain = new X509Chain();
        chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck;
        chain.Build(certificate);

        
        if (chain.ChainStatus.Length == 0)
        {
          Console.WriteLine("Trusted certificate.");
        }
        else
        {
          Console.WriteLine("Untrusted certificate.");
        }
      }
      else
      {
        Console.WriteLine("Certificate not found.");
      }
    }
    finally
    {
      store.Close();
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you very much in advance, and I eagerly look forward to further assistance! Best regards!

Comment: Not sure but this huge combination of key storage flags looks excessive.

Comment: I tried modifying the code by instantiating the `X509Certificate2` class like this:
```
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(certFilePath, "" , X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
```
as instructed in the question from the link below, but without success:

[Trying to add a self signed SSL certificate to a .NET CORE webapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76438676/trying-to-add-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-to-a-net-core-webapi)

Comment: It could also be the TLS, maybe the server lacks the 1.2/1.3. [Try forcing it](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/core/compatibility/aspnet-core/5.0/kestrel-default-supported-tls-protocol-versions-changed)